# How to check duplicate email address without pressing button?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application which should check for duplicate email address live without pressing a button. This checking has to be checked with database data. Please help me on this as I am new in javascript.

Thanks a lot @Scandinave for helping me out. But when I am writing into the textbox it is not getting into the code file (i.e. not firing the method). here is what I am trying:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            //Listen for change event
            $("input[name='TextBox1']").keyup(function () {
                //Get input fields values
                var $email1 = $("input[name='TextBox1']").val();
                //Make ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx.cs/test",
                    data: { email1: $email1}
                }).done(function (msg) {
                    //Check the JSON result send by backend
                    if (msg === "true") {
                        console.log("emails are identicals");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have not tried yet as I am new in Javascript and Ajax. But I need this to be done on client side. thanks.

Comment: I tested your code, and the event is fired. What browser do you use to test? and which version of Jquery, 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I am using google chrome and Jquery 1.3

Comment: Are you sure your textbox is called TextBox1 it may not be if you're using webforms....

Comment: Maybe you don't rename your input as TextBox1?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox> this is my input box

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is the way to achive this. Just listen to "onChange" event on your input field and make an ajax call.So if you have two field like this :

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="your email address"/>
<input type="email" name="confirmeEmail" placeholder="Confirm your email"/>
```

You can use jQuery to make an ajax Call to your backend. Something like this :

```
// wait for all Document to be load. 
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Listen for change event
    $("input[name='confirmEmail']").keyup(function() {
        //Get input fields values
        var $email1 = $("input[name='email']").val();
        var $email2 = $("input[name='confirmEmail']").val();
        //Make ajax request
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "your-backend-adresse",
            data: { email1: $email1, email2: $email2 }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            //Check the JSON result send by backend
            if(msg === "true") {
                 console.log("emails are identicals");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

There is more simple, without request to the backend. But you can't do additional validation like "email exist" that you can do with the response above.

```
// wait for all Document to be load. 
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Listen for change event
    $("input[name='confirmEmail']").keyup(function() {
        //Get input fields values
        var $email1 = $("input[name='email']").val();
        var $email2 = $("input[name='confirmEmail']").val();
        //Check if email are identical. 
        if($email1 === $email2) {
            console.log('Email identical');
        }
    });
});
```

Here we just check that $email1 is equals to $emails and display an message in the console.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But I am new in javascript and ajax so that I can't understand how do I check on backend and connect with this ajax script. Please help me to understand.

Comment: I dont know C# but you must have something equivalent to Java Servlet that is accessible by an url. This is this URL that you pass to jQuery ajax function. Inside your backend you should check if the two address are identical or not and return true or false in Json format, so jQuery can handle it in it's "done" function. The link between jQuery script and your backend is an url

Comment: Thanks again for the nice reply. But getting syntax issue into the Jquery part.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the code without testing it. I have corrected the syntax.

Comment: You can mark the question as resolve if you are satisfied

Comment: I am getting an error please check my updated question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention more details about your requirement here. There are lots of articles freely available online for your query.

You can do something like below:-

```
private void CheckEmail(ref string EmailAddress)
{
    if ((ds.Tables("Check") != null))
    {
        ds.Tables("Check").Clear();
    }
    string str = "select * from yourtablename where Email='" + EmailAddress + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, Con);
    Con.Open();
    Da.Fill(ds, "Check");

    if (ds.Tables("Check").Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        lbl.text = "Email Exists";
    }
    else
    {
        lbl.text = "Email Not fount";
    }
    Con.Close();
}
```

**NOTE** you can create `STORED PROCEDURE` as my query is prone to sql injection. It was just for logic base.

Also you can check the below article for your requirement.

**[Check Email Id duplicate or not](http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/preventing-duplicate-data-with-asp-net-ajax)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I need to check on client side using Javascript or Jquery. But I don't know how to do so.

Comment: is there any special reason for using javascript or jquery ??

Comment: Because my requirement is to check the email address live but not after pressing Enter.